# No fun, enjoyment, laughter for muslims?

Tags: quran, practical-islam, fiqh, tafseer

English translation of the Quran by Dr Ghali:

> [Quran-53:57](http://quran.com/53/57)
> The Imminent is imminent; <- as in the day of judgement is
>   approaching
>
> [Quran-53:58](http://quran.com/53/58)
> Apart from Allah, none can lift it off. <- no one can stop
>   it other than Allah
>
> [Quran-53:59](http://quran.com/53/59)
> Do you then wonder at this discourse, <- as in , wondering
>   about the quran
>
> [Quran-53:60](http://quran.com/53/60)
> And do you laugh, and do you not weep. <- wasting time
>   lauging instead of crying about the approaching judgement
>
> [Quran-53:61](http://quran.com/53/61)
> (While) you amuse yourselves? <- wasting time entertaining
>   and enjoying life instead of preparing for judgement day.

I'm hoping that I have misunderstood these verses, but it seems that as muslims, we should not be laughing, having fun, enjoying life, and entertaining ourselves?

(Sunni view preferred)

Comment: there are several hadith describing the prophet (SAW) having fun, laughing etc. - the verses you list have a context, interpreting them outside their context leads to wrong conlusions!

Comment: That is what I was hoping for, that I've not understood it correctly.  So what is the context of these verses?

Comment: the context is different for each verse... but very often they refer to kuffaar and/or mushrikin people who take this life as "fun..." without any thought about future consequences...

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the verses you list: they can only be interpreted correctly in their context... which usually involves some people (kuffar/mushrikin) which took life as being all fun without any though about future... this does not refer to muslims directly. It is just a warning to make "fun/laughing etc." too high a priority...

Muslims are allowed to have fun, laugh etc. - this is encouraged... There are several Hadith describing the Prophet (SAW + PBUH) joking/laughing with his companions, wifes etc.

Islam sets some groundrules like "no backbiting, no lies, no scaring..." when joking. Like with everything in this life the POV of Islam is that nothing should be done excessively which also applies to fun/joking/laughing etc.

Further references (including Hadiths etc.):

- http://islamqa.info/en/ref/22170
- http://islamqa.info/en/ref/71184
- http://islamqa.info/en/ref/4893